# handling special char in mysql statement

Tags: mysql

how can I replace and handle `speical char` like `% ' " & [space] ! @ # $ % ^ * & ( )` and other special char in mysql statement?

Comment: If you use it in table or column names you could surround the name with ``

Comment: yes. only ' this one gave problem. need to code with another ' . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to [escape them (documentation)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html):

> ```
> Sequence
> \0    An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
> \'    A single quote (“'”) character.
> \"    A double quote (“"”) character.
> \b    A backspace character.
> \n    A newline (linefeed) character.
> \r    A carriage return character.
> \t    A tab character.
> \Z    ASCII 26 (Control+Z). See note following the table.
> \\    A backslash (“\”) character.
> \%    A “%” character. See note following the table.
> \_    A “_” character. See note following the table.
> ```